# what is used to make magento admin - itself

Tags: php, magento

i saw this:

http://demo.videowatchpro.com/administrator/index.php

Login: Admin

Password: VideoWatchPro

and noticed it look just like magento admin

are both using same tools to create Admin?

Answer (score 2):

Well, they're both using the same tools, and the tool is Magento.  It looks like someone installed Magento and used it to create the site at http://demo.videowatchpro.com